# Gem date_validator not working Ruby 1.9.3 Rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I've just installed this gem with:

```
gem install 'date_validation'
```

And I can see it's properly installed, as it appears in the list when I use:

```
gem list
```

But when I try to validate the content of a field form as a date, I get this error:

```
ArgumentError in ProductesController#new
Unknown validator: 'DateValidator'
```

I use this code to validate:

```
validates :data_caducitat, :date => { :after => Proc.new { Time.now } }
```

Any idea of what may be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A simple date validator for Rails 3. Compatible with Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.2 and Rubinius 1.2.2.

That is what they write at https://github.com/codegram/date_validator

Could be that it is not compatible with 1.9.3 version

---

Use this one instead.

https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness

Works for me !